# Spring query method fetching from MongoDB collection that satisfy the condition of two fields

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I use MongoDB and Spring.
I need to fetch from MongoDB collection documents that satisfy the condition of date and time.
The date and time stored in two different fields as strings.
Here example of the document:

```
  {
  "_id":{"$oid":"aaaaaaaaa"},
  "date":{"$date":"2020-12-14T16:30:00.936Z"},
  "potentialUserId":"5fd6d8d3c766eb16c1acd1d1",
  "strDate":"2020-12-14",
  "strTime":"6:30",
  }
```

Currently I fetch from collection above all documents by date range only and I use custom find query:

```
public interface MeetingRepository extends MongoRepository<Meeting, String> {
    List<Meeting> findByStrDateBetween(String startDay, String endDay);
}
```

As I mentioned above I want to fetch from collection documents that satisfy condition not only of the date
but also a time.

so for this purpose, I can also to pass a range of time:

```
List<Meeting> findByStrDateBetween(String startDay, String endDay, String startTime, String endTime);
```

But also I need to change a text of function name:

```
findByStrDateBetween
```

so it will filter not only by strDate field but also by strTime field.

My question is how to change `findByStrDateBetween` that it will satisfy both conditions?

Comment: Most likely need a custom `@Query` or to use a combination of `greaterThan` and `lessThan`

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider thank you for the post. Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

There is another option in order to achieve this by creating an interface annotated `@NoRepositoryBean` with your method of retrieving data, afterwards create a class which implements the interface that you created.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MeetingHandlingRepository {

List<Meeting> findByStrDateBetween(String startDay, String endDay, String startTime, String endTime); 
}
```

Your interface will be like:

```
public interface MeetingRepository extends MongoRepository<Meeting, String>, MeetingHandlingRepository {
    List<Meeting> findByStrDateBetween(String startDay, String endDay, String startTime, String endTime); 
}
```

Your custom implementation of interface:

```
public MeetingHandlingRepositoryImpl implements MeetingHandlingRepository {
 private final MongoTemplate mongo;

 public MeetingHandlingRepositoryImpl (final MongoTemplate mongo) {
    this.mongo = mongo;
 }

 @Override
 public List<Meeting> findByStrDateBetween(String startDay, String endDay, String startTime,String endTime) {
 // your implementation mongo.find(new Query().......);
 }
}
```